# JLabel not updating

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

so thanks for looking at my question,Well anyways im trying to make a cookie clicker clone (if you could call it that) where you click the button and the JPanel updates, unfortunately the JPanel doesn't update and I just cant find an answer anywhere else, Any help is valuable help, thank you! Here is my code:

```
    public int numCookies;

public main(){

    //JButton
    JButton click = new JButton("Click");
    click.setLayout(null);
    click.setLocation(50, 50);
    click.setSize(80, 50);
    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            numCookies = numCookies + 1;
        }
    });

//JLabel
JLabel cookies = new JLabel();
cookies.setLayout(null);
cookies.setText("Cookies:" + numCookies);
cookies.setLocation(480/2,10);
cookies.setSize(200, 50);

    //JPanel
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setLocation(10, 0);
    panel.setSize(260, 30);
    panel.add(click);
    panel.add(cookies);

    //JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie clicker!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 480);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);

}

public static void main(String args[]){

    new main();

}
```

Comment: I see `setLayout(null);` and aren't surprised you're having issues...use an appropriate [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), no execuses

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Three things...

### One...

Use of `null` layouts.  Don't be surprised when things go wrong.  When using `JLabel` or `JButton`, unless you intend to actually add something to them, you don't need to touch there layout managers.

Make use of [approriate layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

### Two...

Calling `setVisible` on your frame before you've finished filling it out...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie clicker!");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600, 480);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
// No idea what you expect this to be doing...
pack();
//frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(panel);    
// This belongs here...and you shouldn't pack a window until
// it's ready to be made visible...
frame.setVisible(true);
```

### Three...

You seem to expect that the lable will magically now that the value `numCookies` has changed...

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        numCookies = numCookies + 1;
        // ??????
    }
```

You need to reassign the value to the label in order for the label to be updated...

For example...

```
public main(){
    //JLabel
    // Make the lable final...so we can access from witin
    // the listener...
    final JLabel cookies = new JLabel();
    cookies.setText("Cookies:" + numCookies);

    //JButton
    JButton click = new JButton("Click");
    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            numCookies = numCookies + 1;
            cookies.setText("Cookies:" + numCookies);
        }
    });
```

### Bonus

Make sure you read through and understand [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

...And just because `null` layouts annoy me so much...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public int numCookies;

    public Main() {

        final JLabel cookies = new JLabel();
        cookies.setText("Cookies:" + numCookies);

        JButton click = new JButton("Click");
        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cookies.setText("Cookies:" + (++numCookies));
            }
        });

        //JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie clicker!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        frame.add(cookies, gbc);
        frame.add(click, gbc);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the text of the JLabel in the actionPerformed method like this:

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        numCookies = numCookies + 1;
        cookies.setText("Cookies:" + numCookies);
    }
});
```